Child killed by a train, mother continues to hear train sounds
I can't remember the movie title and it's about 10 years old, but is about a mother who looses her little child that got killed by a train.
She lives inside a really big house with a friend and her husband and the mother hears a train sound and asks if anyone hears it to! But everyone says no she continues to hear the sound thinking she has gone crazy she finds a black cord and follows it throughout the house until it leads to a bedroom with a tape recorder playing a train sound over and over 
Please help me to know what this movie is called

This might be Remember Me with Kelly McGillis, based on Mary Higgins Clark's bestselling novel. It's about a grieving wife who lost her son when her car was hit by an oncoming train. She moves with her husband to a mansion that's reputed to be haunted, rented to them by a realtor friend who's also her husband's old flame. Soon the wife starts having nightmares and hears her son's voice as well as a rushing train. This turns out to be set up by the husband and the realtor, trying to drive the wife insane. It's from 1995, though. Here's the trailer:



